# Python Cryptography Fernet : Error during decryption

Tags: python, cryptography, fernet

Key is generated and persisted in env file in below format :

SECRET_KEY = KG0TUB0grHz1AngJUwcsN4jcRlujde5sbzbeJ8InZsI=

```
    def encrypt_message(message):
        key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']
        encoded_message = message.encode()
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted_message = f.encrypt(encoded_message)
    
        print(encrypted_message)
    
    
    def decrypt_message(encrypted_message):
        key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']
        f = Fernet(key)
        decrypted_message = f.decrypt(encrypted_message)
    
        print(decrypted_message.decode())
```

Encryption works fine without error. But, during decryption getting below error:

1. When Key is persisted as byteString :

   **b'KG0TUB0grHz1AngJUwcsN4jcRlujde5sbzbeJ8InZsI='**

   `ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes`
2. When Key is persisted as String

   **KG0TUB0grHz1AngJUwcsN4jcRlujde5sbzbeJ8InZsI=**

   `TypeError: token must be bytes`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904080/9215267) help?

Comment: Nope. My token is already persisted as "KG0TUB0grHz1AngJUwcsN4jcRlujde5sbzbeJ8InZsI=". Getting issue while decrypting. Encryption works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution : Encode both key and message**

```
def decrypt_message(encrypted_message):
    key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']         # KG0TUB0grHz1AngJUwcsN4jcRlujde5sbzbeJ8InZsI=
    f = Fernet(key.encode())               #Encode key
    decrypted_message = f.decrypt(encrypted_message.encode())  #Encode Message

    print(decrypted_message.decode())
```